# Use form parameters in a route with Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Imagine I have the following in my routes.php file:

```
Route::get('/test/{system}/{link}', function($system,$link)
{
    return "test ok";
});
```

Then, I wanna access this route with a form from my view:

```
<form action="/" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="system">
    <input type="text" name="link">
    <button type="submit">Go!</button>
<form>
```

What would be the best way to do that? I know I can do something like:

```
Route::get('/',function(){
    $input = Request::only('link','system');
    $url = 'test/'.$input['system'].'/'.$input['link'];
    return redirect($url);
});
```

But I'm not sure if it's the correct way to achieve it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have js change the form action and then submit it. Your way is ok, but make sure to put it at the end of the routes file. I would actually have the form submit to some specific route (instead of `/` maybe `/redirect-to` or something) and from there redirect.

Comment: Actually, i have a js right now, just thought there should be a more backend-ish way to do it. And of course, I have a specific route, the above was just an example. It seems my idea wasn't that far, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. I'm not sure if this is the best process.

In `routes.php`, do this:

```
Route::get('/form', function(){
    return View::make('formview');
});

Route::get('/formaction', function(){
    $link = Request::input('link');
    $system = Request::input('system');
    return "$link";
});
```

And in the view, as usual, the following:

```
<form method="get" action="formaction">
    System: <input type="text" name="system" />
    Link: <input type="text" name="link" />
    <input type="submit" value="ok" />
</form>
```

The `Request` of Laravel does not depend on the verb used for the request.

Comment: I need to have /test/{system}/{link} because i use it for other purposes (REST).